# Erro ao consumir webservice

Tags: php, web-service, soap

Estou com dúvidas sobre como passar os parâmetros para consumir um webservice.
Da forma que estou fazendo, tenho como retorno o erro a baixo:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object hasn't 'ListaDadosCV' property in /srv/www/htdocs/wwwintranet/nusoap_ex/sap_xml.php:250 Stack trace: #0 /srv/www/htdocs/wwwintranet/nusoap_ex/sap_xml.php(250): SoapClient->__soapCall('InputCV', Array) #1 {main} thrown in /srv/www/htdocs/wwwintranet/nusoap_ex/sap_xml.php on line 250
```

O arquivo wsdl:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:cv="http://agraria.com/po/hcm/cv">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <cv:MT_CV_INBOUND_Request>
         <ListaDadosCV>
            <Endereco>
               <Numero>?</Numero>
               <Complemento>?</Complemento>
               <Bairro>?</Bairro>
               <Cidade>?</Cidade>
               <CEP>?</CEP>
               <Estado>?</Estado>
               <Celular>
                  <Tipo>?</Tipo>
                  <Numero>?</Numero>
               </Celular>
               <Residencial>
                  <Tipo>?</Tipo>
                  <Numero>?</Numero>
               </Residencial>
               <Comercial>
                  <Tipo>?</Tipo>
                  <Numero>?</Numero>
               </Comercial>
               <Email>?</Email>
            </Endereco>
         </ListaDadosCV>
      </cv:MT_CV_INBOUND_Request>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

A parte relevante do código php:

```
<?php

require_once('nusoap.php');



try {  
    $client = new soapclient(
    'SI_CV_WS_Outb_SyncService.wsdl',
    array(
        'proxy_host' => "mv114.agraria.coop.br",
        'proxy_port' => 50000,
        'proxy_login' => "WSPO",
        'proxy_password' => "WAgr9876",
        'trace' => 1, 
        'exceptions' => true, 
        'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE
         )
    );
} catch (Exception $e) {  
    echo $e->getMessage(); 
} 




$Endereco = array(
                        'Numero'                 => '?',
                        'Complemento'            => '?',
                        'Bairro'                 => '?',
                        'Cidade'                 => '?',
                        'CEP'                    => '?',
                        'Estado'                 => '?',
                        'Celular'       => array(
                                    'Tipo'      => '?',
                                    'Numero'    => '?'
                                    ),
                        'Residencial'   => array(
                                    'Tipo'      => '?',
                                    'Numero'    => '?'
                                    ),
                        'Comercial'     => array(
                                    'Tipo'      => '?',
                                    'Numero'    => '?'
                                    ),
                        'Email'                 => '?'
                    );

$function = 'InputCV';
$ListaDadosCV = array(

                        $Endereco,
                                                );

$MT_CV_INBOUND_Request = array('ListaDadosCV' => $ListaDadosCV);

$arguments = $MT_CV_INBOUND_Request;

$result = $client->__soapcall($function, $arguments);

?>
```

Porque está dando esse erro? Estou passando os parâmetros de forma incorreta?

Desde já agradecido.

Comment: Tente `$client->listaDadosCV($endereco)` ao invés de `$client->__soapcall($function, $arguments)`

Comment: Fiz da forma como me disse @gmsantos e também dessa forma:

Comment: Fiz da forma como me disse @gmsantos e também dessa forma: 
$result = $client->InputCV($arguments);

Mas ambas não funcionaram e o erro continua.

Comment: qual erro retorna com $client->listaDadosCV($endereco) ?

Comment: O erro abaixo @gmsantos

Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] Function ("listaDadosCV") is not a valid method for this service 

é que a função no server é a inputCV

Comment: vc mesmo q esta desenvolvendo o server do soap? parece q o erro ta nele e é coisa de encoding